# Check if started service is already running

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service

I have a **service** that is being started every time I start my application or the device reboots, but i recently noticed that the service can run multiple times at once, so every time its being called, it just stacks up and eventually the battery draining becomes insane.

Does anyone know  how to check if a service is already running?

Here is the code for starting the service:

```
intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(NotificationService));
Application.Context.StartService(intent);
```

Its in the **MainActivity** class in the **OnCreate** function, called after all the other code inside the function is done.

The service class is as follows:

```
[Service (Label = "ITMNotificationService")]
class NotificationService : Service
{
    ...

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        ...

        UpdateNotification();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // This is a started service, not a bound service, so we just return null.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Inside is a Task that i got running every X time:

```
    private void UpdateNotification()
    {
        Task.Delay(updateTimer).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            ...

            UpdateNotification();

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

I want to have only one instance of the service, since there is no reason to have multiple ones and its just hogging the battery.

Everything I think that is relevant for the service I have added here, if there is something im missing please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

Your service will only have one instance if it is started multiple times - multiple calls to `startService()`.

You will get for each `startService()` call a corresponding `onStartCommand` callback, but it will be on the same instance, Android will not create multiple instances of the same service component.

```
class NotificationService : Service
{
    ...
    boolean isStarted = false;
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        ...

        if (!isStarted) {
            isStarted = true;
            UpdateNotification();
        }

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
{
    // This is a started service, not a bound service, so we just return null.
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: I have a Task in my service that makes a call to a function(s) every X seconds, might it be the task that is being stacked up? I am getting for example 5 or more times(depending on the started time and times) updates of a statistic instead of once per second.

Comment: Your code in onStartCommand needs to handle being called when your task is already running.

Comment: Any idea on how to do that? Im very new to android development - less than a month.

Comment: I don't know what your task is, but simplest way is to use a field boolean as flag if you started your work in service or not

Comment: Ive updated the question with the Task code, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @elmorabea ,I've added a `public static bool isStarted;` in the service class, that way you can check if a service is started or not.

Turned out to be simpler than trying to find some fancy android-based code that I was searching for